# Android API class diagram

Tags: android, class-diagram

I was wondering if there a class diagram available for Android API on the internet? I think it help you to learn and visualize the system in your head.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a great categorized list of classes in the Android API in both PDF and Visio formats, from Troodon Software: http://gyurigrell.com/2011/1/17/great-android-class-diagram-poster

While it's not a class diagram, it is still quite useful. Maybe I'll get around to creating a proper hierarchical class diagram at some point...

Answer (score 1):

This diagram helped me: http://www.adakoda.com/adakoda/2010/01/20/ASPH_AW_REV1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It may be kinda old, but you could find a Android classes poster here:

http://gyurigrell.com/2011/01/great-android-class-diagram-poster/

Answer (score 0):

Could you not check out the source code ? Any decent IDE can create a class diagram from the source code. That way you will have both the code and the underlying design.

Of course android is available in Git
https://android.googlesource.com